# Async function returning undefined variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to return a boolean from an async function, but is is coming out as `undefined`.

```js
checkIfEmptyDb = async => {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("dynamicDb");
    ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
      const a = snapshot.exists();
      console.log(a); // false
      return a;
    });
  };

  getRandomWordFromDb = async () => {
    let moreWords = await this.checkIfEmptyDb();
    console.log("moreWords", moreWords); //UNDEFINED
```

My solution so far is to set the state of the react app in the `checkIfEmptyDb`function, which then can be called in `getRandomWordFromDb`..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: forgot to add a return here:  return ref.once("value").then()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value of the promise:

```js
  checkIfEmptyDb = async => {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("dynamicDb");
    return ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
      const a = snapshot.exists();
      console.log(a); // false
      return a;
    });
  };
```